# IF construct in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Can anyone help me perform the following...

example:

```
      A    B C D

row 1 ODZN 2 3 

row 2 EAXO 3 4
```

I need a IF then statement which gives this logic...

1. If `A:1` is `ODZN,` then `D1=(B:1)*(C:1)*5` , else if
2. If `A:2` is `EAXO`, then `D1=(B:2)*(C:2)*20` ... and so on with different variables....
   every different variable has a different multiplier.......

and I'll copy and drag the formula down a large set of data and eventually into a macro

could anyone help.. and possibly advise me what I need to define as a variable...

The multiplier is set by me manually. The variables will be defined in excel.

Thanks!!

Comment: where 3 and 10 come from, why D1  has 2 value

Comment: @Michael Downey: Please choose a question title that is more descriptive than "Excel VBA Question".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you mean:

> for a row, if value in column A is ODZN / EAXO, then value in column D gets a multiplier 5 / 20.

Answer:

```
=B1*C1*IF(A1="ODZN",5,IF(A1="EAXO",20,0))
```

and then drag.

You can nest as many `IF` as you want. (Here I use I an unnecessary `0` to show how `IF` can be nested, it can be simplified as `IF(A1="ODZN",5,20)`).

Of course, you can write a function, then it will be like

```
=B1*C1*func(A1)
```

However, macros need authentication to run in later versions of Excel. I would recommend the formula solution if the value variation is not that many.